# How to don't show menu item in Action Overflow?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, menuitem

My meny code is:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/action_map"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"
        android:title="Add"

        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings" />
</menu>
```

My Fragment code is:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_where_am_i, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return root;
}
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.where_i_am_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.action_map:

            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And i get next action bar. Why i have 2 settings in that list? And i don't want to add label "Add" to that list, hiw can i make it?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to add label "Add" to that list" ? Because, the "Add" item is currently not in the list, it is in the action bar. The only problem you have is the "Settings" item which is displayed twice.

Comment: Don't that super. methods need to be executed first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clear the menu:

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.where_i_am_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Hope it helps you :)